# ¿ Resultados sin mostrar PHP PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola amigos resulta que estoy haciendo una consulta a la base dedatos mysql con PDO y resulta que no me esta devolviendo todas las filas y no se porque.

Les explico cuando hago la consulta en phpmyadmin si me devuelve todos los resultados.

Pero cuando la hago en php la misma consulta no me devuelve todas las filas que necesito.
Ahora comento un poco el codigo

Tengo esta consulta que anda perfectamente me tira los datos qeu quiero.

```
SELECT 
comentarios.id,
comentarios.id_user,
comentarios.comentario,
comentarios.date_comented,
respuestas.respuesta,
respuestas.id_user,
respuestas.id_comentario,
respuestas.date_responsed,
usersc.username as user_c,
respuestas.id as id_r,
usersc.img_user as img_user_c,
usersc.username as user_r,
usersr.img_user as img_user_r
LEFT JOIN respuestas ON respuestas.id_comentario = comentarios.id
LEFT JOIN users as usersc ON comentarios.id_user=usersc.id
LEFT JOIN users as usersr ON respuestas.id_user=usersr.id
where id_post=2 ORDER BY id ASC
```

La consulta anda perfecta no es el promblema

El problema es que cuando la ejecuto en php con pdo no me devuelve todos los datos. Como pueden ver es un left join de comentarios y respuesta osea que tiene una relacion de 1 a muchos.

ahora muestro el codigo php

la query es la misma

```
//la conexion ya esta lista 
$query='SELECT comentarios.id, comentarios.id_user,
comentarios.comentario,
comentarios.date_comented,
respuestas.id as id_r, respuestas.respuesta,
respuestas.id_user, respuestas.id_comentario,
respuestas.date_responsed,usersc.username as user_c,
usersc.img_user as img_user_c,
usersc.username as user_r, usersr.img_user as img_user_r 

FROM comentarios 
LEFT JOIN respuestas ON respuestas.id_comentario = comentarios.id 
LEFT  JOIN users as usersc ON comentarios.id_user=usersc.id  
LEFT JOIN users as usersr ON respuestas.id_user=usersr.id
WHERE id_post=:id_post 
ORDER BY comentarios.id ASC ';

$sql= $this->db->prepare($query);
//aca abajo bindeo todos los parametros con un bucle for por la logica que tengo de hacer esto.. esto no es importante proque funciona bien solo lo comento

$sql->execute();
while ($r=$sql->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $result[$r['id']]=$r;
    }

return $result
```

basicamente cuando ejecuto esa consulta en phpmyadmin me devuelve 9 resultados pero cuando lo hago en pdo me devuleve 7 y no entiendo porque si alguno a pasado por esto y sabe la solucion le agradeceria mucho la ayuda.
Espero se entienda la query anda perfectamente en phpmyadmind me devuelve todo bien el problema es en php que no me devuelve todos los resultados.
Sera el FETCH_ASSOC el problema? porque este tipo de consulta me devuelve el comentario repetido pero con una respuesta distinta en la misma fila. pero en php me esta devolviendo solamente una respuesta para cada comentario, en un comentario tengo 3 respuestas y solo me devuelve 1 en php pdo, en phpmyadmin me devuelve todo bien.

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer ahí: `$result[$r['id']]=$r;`?  Debes llenar el array a cada paso del `while` con algo como: `$result[]=$r;`  y, si sólo te interesa un array con los ids: `$result[]=$r['id'];`

Comment: La respuesta debe ir en la seccion respuestas, con una explicacion de lo que pasaba.

Comment: Revertí tu edición, te comento que la respuesta va en la zona de abajo destinada a ello y no en la pregunta misma

Comment: okey amigo lo siento por eso y muchas gracias